# SWIFT: Data not polulation Graph from webapi

Tags: ios, graph, swift3

I am new to IOS development and facing issue to display data in graph from alamofire. I am posting my code below. Please help me!!!
Issue: Not able to get Alamofire service response. Data not populating on y axis which we get from webAPI.

Graph reference: https://github.com/T-Pro/Scrollable-GraphView

```
    let credentialData = "\(user):\(passwort)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
    let headers = ["Accept": "application/xml","Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]
            Alamofire.request(
                              url!,
                              method: .get,
                              parameters: nil,
                              encoding: URLEncoding.default,
                              headers:headers)

                .responseString
                {           response in

                    debugPrint(response)
                    print(response.request)  // original URL request
                    print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
                    print(response.data)     // server data
                    print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

                    if response.result.value != nil
                    {
                        self.xml = try! XML.parse(response.result.value!)
                    }                
                    }

        // Data Generation
        private func generateRandomData(_ numberOfItems: Int, max: Double, shouldIncludeOutliers: Bool = true) -> [Double] {
            var data = [Double]()
            var counter = 1                
            for _ in 0 ..< numberOfItems
            {                    
                for Result in xml["WebAPiResponse","Result"]
                {
                    let SLPercent = Result["SLPercent"].text!;
                    let Date = Result["DateCST"].text!;
                    let DateFromService = Int(Date.substring(to:Date.index(Date.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)))
                    if (counter == DateFromService!)
                    {                    
                        data.append(Double(SLPercent)!)                           
                    }                      
                }        
                //data.append(Double(counter))
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
            return data
        }

        private func generateRandomData(_ numberOfItems: Int, variance: Double, from: Double) -> [Double] {                
            var data = [Double]()
            for _ in 0 ..< numberOfItems {        
                let randomVariance = Double(arc4random()).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: variance)
                var randomNumber = from                
                if(arc4random() % 100 < 50) {
                    randomNumber += randomVariance
                }
                else {
                    randomNumber -= randomVariance
                }                  
                data.append(randomNumber)                    
            }
            return data
        }

        private func generateSequentialLabels(_ numberOfItems: Int, text: String) -> [String] {
            var labels = [String]()
            for i in 0 ..< numberOfItems {
                labels.append("\(text) \(i+1)")
            }
            return labels
        }
```

Comment: Can you please fix your question so all of your code is within the code block?  You could also definitely benefit from adding comments to your code, splitting this huge code block into smaller chunk with comments, etc.  Hard to help if we can't understand easily how the code is pieced together

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question